# Disable add to cart if in quantity box is 0

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm looking for solution for my problem. I have category list with add to cart button and quantity box. I need to disable add to cart when is in quantity box 0 and allow it when is 1 and more. 
I need default value 0. 
Now, when I click to add to cart button is added one product to the cart.

This problem is just in category list, not on product page.

My code from /app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<?php  if ( !($product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasOptions($product)/*$_product->getData('has_options')*/ || $product->isGrouped()) ) :  ?>

                                <div class="qty-holder">
                                    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $product->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
                                    <div class="qty-changer">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_inc" style="height:34px; line-height:34px;"><i class="icon-up-dir"></i></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_dec" style="height:34px; line-height:34px;"><i class="icon-down-dir"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <?php $_productid == $_product->getId(); ?>

                            <a href="<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code) && !Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/qty_field", $code)): ?><?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?><?php else: ?>javascript:void(0)<?php endif; ?>" class="addtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code)):?>onclick="setLocationAjax(this,'<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')"<?php elseif(Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/qty_field", $code)): ?>onclick="document.getElementById('addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>').submit()"<?php endif; ?>><i class="icon-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></a>

                        <?php else : ?>
                            <a href="<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code)):?>javascript:showOptions('<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')<?php else: ?><?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?><?php endif; ?>" class="addtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>"><i class="icon-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></a>
                            <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajaxcart/index/options',array('product_id'=>$_product->getId()));?>' class='fancybox' id='fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style='display:none'>Options</a>
                        <?php endif;?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this (javascript):

```
jQuery('.addtocart').each(function() {
    var $self = jQuery(this),
        oldOnClick = $self.attr('onclick'),
        $product = $self.closest('.item');

    $self.attr('data-onclick', oldOnClick).removeAttr('onclick');
    $self.off('click').on('click', function() {
        if($product.find('.input-text.qty').val() < 1)
            return false;
        else
            eval(jQuery(this).data('onclick'));
    });
});
```

When user clicks on 'add to cart', check if the quantity value is >= 1.

**Edit:** fix some things..

Comment: I tried add your code into my javascript codes, and nothing change. Still is possible to add product with qty 0.

Comment: Do you have the category page online? Could you send us the link?

Comment: Yes. Here: http://aquanew.web-testovani.cz/zeleny-stitek-63.html?mode=list

Comment: Thaanks! Now it's working for grid version of category list. I need to do some editions and it will be perfect! 
Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. If you could, choose the answear as the correct one.

Comment: I still have one problem. If I go to the page first time, the solution is not working, but when I change from list to grid (or other way), than it is working. Do you know where could be problem please?

Comment: Where are you putting the js code? Try put it all inside `jQuery(document).ready(function() { [here] });`.

Comment: To the theme java script file. Now it's working. Thank you Lucas!!

Answer (score 0):

Put this condition to disable addtocart and add disabled="disbled" in anchor tag of add to cart

```
if($product->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 == 0){
   <a disabled = "disabled"></a>
}
else{
  // your normal code here for add to cart
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but there is problem, after change qty number nothing happend. The system still using disabled version of code.

Comment: check what this code gives value $product->getProductDefaultQty() if it is not 0 then it will go to esle condition